# Android Unit Testing Robolectric:3.3.2 - No such manifest file: build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, android-testing, robolectric

when i am running my tests, following error is showing

```
No such manifest file: build\intermediates\bundles\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to gyg.android.reviews.ReviewApplication
```

Following are Gradle dependencies

```
compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '2.0.2-beta'
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2"
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

This is how i am starting my Test Class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class ReviewListPresenterTest {
```

I am using Roboelectric 3.3.2 with Android Studio 2.3.2
 Quick help will be highly appreciated !

Comment: I am getting this exact same error with the exact same versions of Roboelectric and Android Studio. After some digging, I found that the merged manifest is under `build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug` or `build\intermediates\manifests\instant-run\debug` instead. It seems that AS has changed the output directory structure and Robolectric has not caught up yet.

Comment: I have submitted an Issue on the Robolectric GitHub: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3110

Comment: "I remember when i close Android studio yesterday. These tests were running but not now nor in my new project." Have you updated Android Studio since the last time these tests ran?

Comment: Yes i updated some of SDK updates but not the Android Version.

Comment: Did you upgrade Android Studio?

Comment: I beleive i didn't.

Comment: have you found any solution so far ?

Comment: The issue which I posted on GitHub had a suggested solution. Try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be with an Android Studio project which contains multiple modules. There are two solutions:

1. Run the Robolectric tests from the command line:

   ```
   gradlew :app:testDebugUnitTest
   ```
2. Run the Robolectric tests from Android Studio:

   Open the Edit Run Configurations dialog. Under Defaults > Android JUnit, set the Working Directory to the folder which contains the module you are testing. You will probably also need to set this option for each existing run configuration. If you have tests in multiple modules, you will need to set the Working Directory for each run configuration to the appropriate module.

Comment: So if i send that project to some one else, Will that person do these configurations for each test class on his side as well to run all of my written test successfully ?

Comment: @SalmanNazir if you include the .idea project folder, it contains an XML file with the run configurations. You can also export the Android Studio settings and send the resulting JAR file with your project. The other person will need to import those settings.